# R: doSNOW/foreach create list of list

Tags: r, parallel-processing, doparallel, snow

Hi I would like to create a named list of list using the doSNOW/foreach package.  For example the end product would be a list object. dfe named from a vector say,

```
n=c("n1","n2","n3","n4","n5")
```

so that I can access the list of list object like `dfe[["n1"]]$a` where a is a element in the list.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about.

```
mainStart <- Sys.time()

n=c("n1","n2","n3","n4","n5")

cores=detectCores() 
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoSNOW(cl)

## setup progress bar 
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 5, style = 3)
progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list(progress = progress)


dfe <-  foreach(id.this = n, .combine = list, .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {
    list ( a=c(1,2,3), b = c(1,2,3))
}

endTime <- Sys.time()
endTime -mainStart 


close(pb)
stopCluster(cl)
```

So it would be great if I the list that was created in the foreach loop could be name and access after the loop.  Such that dfe[["n1"]]$a can give me the vector 1,2,3.

Comment: Don't combine, and use setNames(dfe, n) afterwards.

Comment: @F.Privé this is surprising that it works because I thought it would go out of order.  For example when I do, `if ( id.this == "n2"){Sys.sleep(10)}` the order was retain, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above it easier to just to setNames ( dfe, n) however I did not think that would work since some processes might take longer than other but it appears that the order does not change.  For example when I set

```
if ( id.this == "n2"){
        Sys.sleep(10)
    }
```

the order was still retain.  So final code would be something like this.

```
mainStart <- Sys.time()

n=c("n1","n2","n3","n4","n5")

cores=detectCores() 
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(cores[1]-1) #not to overload your computer
registerDoSNOW(cl)

## setup progress bar 
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = 4, style = 3)
progress <- function(n) setTxtProgressBar(pb, n)
opts <- list(progress = progress)


dfe <-  foreach(id.this = n, .options.snow = opts) %dopar% {
    #list(id.this = list(  a=c(1,2,3), b = c(1,2,3) ) )
    if ( id.this == "n2"){
        Sys.sleep(10)
    }
    list(  a=c(id.this,2,3), b = c(1,2,3) )
}

endTime <- Sys.time()
endTime -mainStart 


close(pb)
stopCluster(cl)

dfe=setNames(dfe, n)
```

Comment: Yes, the `foreach()` function respects the order of the input / your iterator regardless of sequential or parallel processing (and how, where, and when). It can do this because all elements are completed before `foreach()` returns.